# Continuity of Hardy Littlewood maximal function $Mf$ when $f$ is continuous

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having a doubt regarding Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.

If $ f $ is continuous, I want to know whether the Hardy Littlewood maximal function $f^*$ be discontinuous.
$$f^*(x)=\sup_{t>0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t} |f| $$
I know that if $f$ is discontinuous, then $f^*$ might be continuous. But I could not find any example for the above case.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10255-020-0983-z Looks related

Comment: Does this link answer you ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392563/sufficient-conditions-for-the-hardy-littlewood-maximal-function-mf-being-con